# Factorial limit from gamma function calculation

Tags: limits, factorial, gamma-function

I want to show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)}{\sqrt{n}\Gamma(n)}=1$$

Using the formula for $\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606696/calculation-of-gamman-frac12), it reduces to $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{(2n)!\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n}\sqrt{n}(n-1)!n!}=1$$

How to prove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going around in circles, since you reduced a problem with two gammas to a problem with three gammas! Instead, the scientific way uses [Stirling's expansion.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) Notice that the second (an in some ways easier) derivation is used for Gamma directly. (in any case, use the Stirling approximation for numerator and denominator, divide, take limits.

Comment: Igor, what is the "second derivation" you're talking about?

Comment: @MikaH. If you look on the wiki page, scroll down to "alternate derivation".

Comment: Okay sure, but I still don't see how that would help solve the current problem.

Comment: @MikaH. You use the stirling approximation for numerator and denominator. What happens when you do?

Answer (score 3):

See "Inequalities for Gamma Function Ratios", 
G.J.O. Jameson, *American Mathematical Monthly*, 
December 2013, pp 936-940.

This recent article gives elementary proofs of 
Gautschi-type inequalities. In particular, you 
get 
$$\left({x\over x+1/2}\right)^{1/2}\leq {\Gamma(x+1/2)\over\sqrt{x}\,\Gamma(x)}\leq 1.$$
Now let $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Nice reference!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the reciprocal of the expression under the limit is just the Euler's beta function (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function) for details):
$$
   \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(n\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)} = \operatorname{B}\left(n, \frac{1}{2}\right) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{\sqrt{1-x}} \mathrm{d}x
$$
Hence, using $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$:
$$
   \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n} \Gamma\left(n\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}  = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{x^{n-1}}{\sqrt{1-x}} \mathrm{d}x \stackrel{x=1-t/n}{=} \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_0^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{\left( 1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{t}} \mathrm{d}t 
$$
Using [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem):
$$
  \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_0^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{\left( 1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{t}} \mathrm{d}t  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty t^{-1/2} \underbrace{\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n-1}}_{\exp(-t)} \mathrm{d}t
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \underbrace{\int_0^\infty t^{-1/2} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \mathrm{d}t}_{\Gamma\left(1/2\right)=\sqrt{\pi}} = 1
$$
Since we established that
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n} \Gamma\left(n\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}  = 1   
$$
the limit in question follows.

Comment: All this to avoid using Stirling? (notice that the integral rep for the beta function (defined in terms of gammas) is not trivial)

Comment: @IgorRivin I agree, it is much easier to use the Stirling formula.